# How to disable space character in a text field in ios xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I don't want to allow to enter space in display name field.

For example if the user types the name like this "  Name" or "   Name" or "  Name  ", the end result should be "Name" eliminating the spaces.

I tried this approach but the trim doesn't seem to work.

```
NameText.EditingDidEnd += delegate {
            char[] arr = new char[] {' '};
            NameText.Text.TrimStart(arr);
            ScrollPageForKeyboard(false);
        };
```

Comment: Why not just do a `.Trim()` after the fact on the `DisplayNameText.Text` value, assuming it is a string?  This will take all the leading and trailing white space off the string.

Comment: `String.Trim()` will trim all white-spaces from start and end of a string. Your `DisplayNameText.Text.TrimStart(arr);` is returning the output string which you need to store: `DisplayNameText.Text = DisplayNameText.Text.TrimStart(arr);`

Comment: `Regex.Replace(yourtext, @"\s", "");`

Comment: I would not worry about all the extra stuff and just use string.Replace function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest **preventing** the user from actually entering whitespace versus removing it **after** they all ready have.

Add a `ShouldChangeCharacters` handler and check to see if they are entering any characters in the whitespace character set as defined by  `NSCharacterSet.WhitespaceAndNewlines`

```
NameText.ShouldChangeCharacters += (UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString) =>
{
    foreach (var aChar in replacementString)
    {
        if (NSCharacterSet.WhitespaceAndNewlines.Contains(aChar))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove leading and trailing spaces (" Name" or "Name "), then use:

```
DisplayNameText.Text = DisplayNameText.Text.Trim()
```

as recommended in the comments.  If you want to remove all spaces ("John Smith" = "JohnSmith"), then use

```
DisplayNameText.Text = DisplayNameText.Text.Replace(" ", "")
```

to remove all the spaces.

Comment: I would recommend using `ShouldChangeCharacters` to prevent the whitespace in the first place, instead of allowing the whitespace characters to be entered and then removing them. Also you should be using the `NSCharacterSet.WhitespaceAndNewlines` to determine if the user is actually entering a whitespace character instead of hardcoding English-based literals

Answer (score 1):

Using the `String.Trim()` method should work nicely here:

```
NameText.EditingDidEnd += delegate
{
    var trimmedName = DisplayNameText.Text.Trim();
    ScrollPageForKeyboard(false);
};
```

You could also use a `Regex` to replace all white space completely:

```
NameText.EditingDidEnd += delegate
{
    var trimmedName = Regex.Replace(DisplayNameText.Text, @"\s+", "");
    ScrollPageForKeyboard(false);
};
```

Comment: You would not need the `char[] arr` here

Comment: I would recommend using `ShouldChangeCharacters` to prevent the whitespace in the first place, instead of allowing the whitespace characters to be entered and then removing them. Also you should be using the `NSCharacterSet.WhitespaceAndNewlines` to determine if the user is actually entering a whitespace character instead of hardcoding English-based literals.