# Remove whitespace from textbox on run time while typing text

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have to remove whitespaces in username textbox android when ever I put . there is always whitespace occurs for example (john. james) like this please let me know how to resolve this problem on while typing there should not be any space in between.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92427/how-to-avoid-empty-space-in-text-field-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable space character in a text field in ios xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031635/how-to-disable-space-character-in-a-text-field-in-ios-xamarin)

Comment: Here is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086881/restricting-input-length-and-characters-for-entry-field-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting input length and characters for Entry field in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086881/restricting-input-length-and-characters-for-entry-field-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, " ", "");
}
```